# Replace non-ASCII characters with SGML entity codes with Emacs

Tags: html, xml, emacs, html-entities, sgml

I have a HTML file with a few non-ASCII characters, say encoded in UTF-8 or UTF-16. To save the file in ASCII, I would like to replace them with their (SGML/HTML/XML) entity codes. So for example, every `ë` should become `&#235;` and every `◊` should become `&#9674;`. How do I do that?

I use Emacs as an editor. I'm sure it has a function to do the replace, but I cannot find it. What am I missing? Or how do I implement it myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [character class](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Char-Classes.html#Char-Classes) which includes exactly the ASCII character set. You can use a regexp that matches its complement to find occurrences of non-ASCII characters, and then replace them with their codes using elisp:

```
M-x replace-regexp RET
[^[:ascii:]] RET
\,(concat "&#" (number-to-string (string-to-char \&)) ";") RET
```

So when, for example, `á` is matched: `\&` is `"á"`, `string-to-char` converts it to `?á` (= the number 225), and `number-to-string` converts that to `"225"`. Then, `concat` concatenates `"&#"`, `"225"` and `";"` to get `"&#225;"`, which replaces the original match.

Surround these commands with `C-x (` and `C-x )`, and apply `C-x C-k n` and `M-x insert-kbd-macro` as usual to make a function out of them.

---

To see the elisp equivalent of calling this function interactively, run the command and then press `C-x M-:` (Repeat complex command).

A simpler version, which doesn't take into account the active region, could be:

```
(while (re-search-forward "[^[:ascii:]]" nil t)
  (replace-match (concat "&#"
                         (number-to-string (string-to-char (match-string 0)))
                         ";")))
```

(This uses the [recommended way](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Search-and-Replace.html#Search-and-Replace) to do search + replace programmatically.)

Comment: Magic... So many gems in one answer! I should have known regexps could take elisp.

Comment: `insert-kbd-macro` creates an ugly keyboard stream; what's the readable form to wrap this into a .emacs `defun`?

Comment: @MicheldeRuiter I added that info to the answer.

Answer (score 5):

I searched high and low but it seems Emacs (or at least version 24.3.1) doesn't have such a function. Nor can I find it somewhere.

Based on a [similar](https://github.com/jkarlsson/emacs-config/blob/master/vendor/ys-xml-escape.el) (but different) function I did find, I implemented it myself:

```
(require 'cl)
(defun html-nonascii-to-entities (string)
  "Replace any non-ascii characters with HTML (actually SGML) entity codes."
  (mapconcat
   #'(lambda (char)
       (case char
             (t (if (and (<= 8 char)
                         (<= char 126))
                    (char-to-string char)
                  (format "&#%02d;" char)))))
   string
   ""))
(defun html-nonascii-to-entities-region (region-begin region-end)
  "Replace any non-ascii characters with HTML (actually SGML) entity codes."
  (interactive "r")
  (save-excursion
    (let ((escaped (html-nonascii-to-entities (buffer-substring region-begin region-end))))
      (delete-region region-begin region-end)
      (goto-char region-begin)
      (insert escaped))))
```

I'm no Elisp guru at all, but this works!

I also found [find-next-unsafe-char](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/FindingNonAsciiCharacters) to be of value.

**Edit:** an interactive version!

```
(defun query-replace-nonascii-with-entities ()
  "Replace any non-ascii characters with HTML (actually SGML) entity codes."
  (interactive)
  (perform-replace "[^[:ascii:]]"
                   `((lambda (data count)
                       (format "&#%02d;" ; Hex: "&#x%x;"
                               (string-to-char (match-string 0)))))
                     t t nil))
```

Comment: I'd recommend you use `(goto-char end) (while (re-search-backward "[^\010-\176]" nil begin) (replace-match (format "&#%02d;" (char-after)) t t))` so as to avoid constructing large strings.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for `iso-iso2sgml`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @JanDoggen, Lets the author decide if this answers the question.  He was asking for an Emacs function to do some stuff; I am telling the name of the function; the author is expert enough in Emacs (as he proved in his answer) to use it.

Comment: Sorry misunderstood the answer

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! Does it also work outside of ISO 8859-1 like for my diamond example?